# How to add a url to the previous browser entry to trigger popstate

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

Let's say I have two pages, *current.html* and *previous.html*, and I navigated to *current.html* from *previous.html*.

So my browser currently is displaying *current.html* as the url, and if I look at the tab history, *previous.html* is displayed as the previous entry.

I want to play a CSS animation on *previous.html* when the user clicks the back from *current.html* (or forward, but I can't even figure out back yet lol) button in their browser.

I am at a loss as to how to do this. My initial thought was using the popstate event. However, this requires me to push an the previous url manually again into the browser history, since popstate only fires when you manually add/replace history entries with push and replacestate (I think?).

The best I could come up with right now is doing a pushstate which sets the url to *previous.html*, and doing history.back, but the order here is the opposite of what I want.

Is there any way I could feasibly do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you got it backwards, [see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event): it's the contrary, the `popstate` event is not triggered when you manually add/remove a state, only when the user clicks back or forward in the browser. When in doubt, always check the docs or try yourself with a simple code

Comment: @Kaddath I've tried testing it without manually added/removed states, as well as just navigating normally, and it seems that popstate will only occur when you manually do it though

Comment: [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unjdk0rc/) shows you the basic behavior: navigating from the browser/links and calling `back()` / `forward()` triggers the event, pushing/removing a state manually doesn't. Hope this clarifies, maybe we didn't understand each other. So you shouldn't need to manipulate history states to trigger your event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `previous.html` page, add a JavaScript code block to listen for the `pageshow` event:

```js
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function(event) {
  if (event.persisted || (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === 2)) {
    // Play your CSS animation here
    console.log('Animation played on previous.html');
  }
});
```

In the `current.html` page, when the user clicks the back button, you can use the `history.replaceState()` method to update the state of the `previous.html` page and trigger the `pageshow` event:

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.href);
});
```

Note: You might need to add additional logic to differentiate between the initial load and the back navigation if needed, because the `pageshow` event will also be triggered on the initial load of the `previous.html` page.

Comment: thanks i'll test this out tmrw morning

Comment: using window.performance sort of worked, but the animation only played a few times before both the forward and backwards keys just loaded the page at the end of the animation, and I'm too tired with this project to bother with any future debugging so i'll do with this

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the issue now, I don't seem to understand your point

Comment: My question basically states my issue, and your fix partially fixes it. I don't want to continue trying to debug this because lazy so it'll do